# Want to create and an array class that adds objects of a class and stores in an array of those objects

Tags: arrays, class, object, input, instantiation

I'm trying to create an array class that stores objects of a class (my data class). The array is then going to be sorted/searched by my sorting/searching algorithm classes
I'm having a little trouble trying to create the objects and store them in the array class.

Here's my code:

This is my Data class:
The value variable generated by this class is a random number and is used for sorting the the array of data. value variable is just a randomly generated number which is in the range of some input given by user.

public class Data {

```
private int value;
private int counter; 
private static int LastCounter = 0; 
InputClass ValueRange;
Random ValGen = new Random();

public Data() {
    value = ValGen.nextInt(ValueRange.getNumRange());
    counter = LastCounter+1;
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public int getCounter() {
    return counter;
}
```

}

This is my input class, it takes input from user to give constraints of the array. arrSize() and ranNumRange() are called to set the parameters.

public class InputClass {

```
int NumRange;
int DataSetSize;
Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);

public void arrSize() {
    System.out.println("Enter the size of the array: ");
    DataSetSize = user.nextInt();
}

public void ranNumRange() {
    System.out.println("Enter the range of random numbers: ");
    NumRange = user.nextInt();
}

public int getArrSize() {
    return DataSetSize;
}

public int getNumRange() {
    return NumRange;
}
```

}

and last class is my array class is unfinished as I'm at a loss in how to best implement it. The constructor initialises the the array and sets the size of the array as enter by the user. The addData method goes through the array and adds a new piece of data to the array. the getSize() will just return size of array once I have the addData method working.

public class ArrayClass implements Array {

```
InputClass arrInput;
Data[] arr;
int size; 

public ArrayClass() { 
    arr = new Data[arrInput.getArrSize()];
}
@Override
public void addData(Data newData) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++)
        arr[i] = new Data();
}

@Override
public int getSize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

}

Appreciate any help thanks.